# How do I see when an object is influenced, and by what?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, gdb

This might be a long shot, but I'm having a bug that I'm fairly sure is specific to my program.  I'm animating something, and between then the animation starts and stops, something is influencing my animated view, and changing it's size.

I was wondering if there was a way in the debugger, or really in anything to see what's influencing my view to mess itself up like it is and when it's doing so.  Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting a breakpoint (or calling `NSLog()`) in the view's `setFrame:` method.  (Add an override if you need to.)